# ProximaNova version upgrade line-height issues

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts, spacing, line-spacing

We are using Proxima Nova font version **2.003** before. Now, we are upgrading it to version **3.017** . There is some `line-height` issue in newer version.

[image]

In above image the left one is old version (2.003) and right one is new version (3.017). I have applied `font-size:32px;` and `font-family: ProximaNova Semibold;` in both cases using a div element without applying any `line-height`.

**Left Side Case Details:**

8,16, 24, 32 & 40 are font-sizes

9, 20, 29, 39 & 49 are div height size it taken

**Right Side Case Details:**

8,16, 24, 32 & 40 are font-sizes (same font-sizes)

12, 23, 35, 47 & 58 are div height size it taken

Now, you can clearly see there is a different height taken in right side div. If you zoom that above image you can clearly see there is top and bottom extra space is added there. I am getting line-height, text vertical align middle issues are happening due to these extra spaces. Is there any way to get rid of these top & bottom extra spaces?

[image]

I have tried setting `line-height` in a div. After setting `line-height` in a div, both left and right side cases taken same div height. But however, line-height issues & vertical align middle issues happening due to new version default spacings. Is there any tricks to remove these spaces?

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this?

Comment: @Ondrej Yes. Solved.

Comment: Excellent :) I am solving the same thing. Any hints?

Comment: @Ondrej Fontspring's (font provider) webfont generator generates wrong metric values. We contacted them and solved the issue.

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked out for you. Sadly, I have issues with getting Proxima Nova through Adobe Typekit (the issue is the same), so I'll have to keep digging.